# IE cuts off right side of text

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an element of, say, 1000px width, and inside is some text. The text is displayed fine in all browsers except in IE, where it looks like the right half is cut off, or like the container is too small and has overflow: hidden (but the container isn't too small).

Oddly enough, it seems like I still can mark the text and all. It is just not showing up.

I tested this in IE11/10.

EDIT//
I attached a screenshot. [image: screenshot]

Comment: You probably need a CSS reset since some browsers have different default values in terms of margins, padding, etc. Either way, without a jsfiddle, a screenshot, or something else to help us solve your problem, we can only guess wildly at your problem

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development.  Please provide a concrete example with code and we would be glad to help you.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Here's also a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9pker8bs/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update:* While this has not yet been resolved in Internet Explorer (or Microsoft Edge), I did want to revisit and share a potential work-around after having this question brought to my attention on Twitter by another engineer.

```css
body {
  text-shadow:
    0 0 1em transparent,
    1px 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 );
}
```

By setting two shadows (the first being much larger), the page is composed and painted differently. You can see the before and after by comparing the following URLs:

- Before: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/96h9czc5/
- After: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/96h9czc5/1/

---

Removing the `<div>&nbsp;</div>` also appears to resolve this.

---

I work on the Internet Explorer team and can confirm that this is a bug with Internet Explorer. For the time being, you could remove your (nearly-imperceivable) `text-shadow` and that should resolve the problem in Internet Explorer.

I have opened up a bug to track the resolution of this internally and will see to it that our Composition team has a look into the matter.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, I still have this problem in some versions of IE11. Does it go away with browser upgrades? It does not happen on IE11/Win7 on emulators like Browserstack (IE version 11.0.9600.17420), but in a local machine we have here it still happens (IE version 11.0.960017691).

Comment: @pm_hce Do you have a demo that repros the issue consistently? I'd be happy to look further into it.

Comment: Hi, I found a solution (see below).

Comment: I tried to setup a JsFiddle with just the "offending" bit of the site, but I cannot reproduce the problem. I will try and put the whole page on a private server when I have time, if you would like me to.

Comment: I've forked the original JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4mvgv9u/
in this case, the text-shadow is applied to the text elements directly and no problem takes place on the latest IE11.

If I look to the original JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9pker8bs/1/
where the text shadow (albeit almost invisible) is applied to the BODY tag, the problem appears.

Tested with 11.0.960017691.

Comment: I had a similar issue on MS Edge 42.17134.1.0 on Windows 10 - the transparent text shadow did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Update to the above - if you already have a text shadow on the offending text, and add a second one to fix the clipping issue in Edge, the browser seems to assume the use of "transparent" is accidental, and applies whatever colour is set in the first property. To get around this I used rgba(0,0,0,0.01) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on IE11/Win7 version 11.0.960017691.
I was applying the thext shadow to the parent container, the bug gets solved if you apply the shadow to individual elements in the container.
For example, in:

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

Apply the shadow to h1 and h2 separately, not to the .container DIV.